# How to migrate Social Engine config?

Tags: php, zend-framework, socialengine

How to migrate a SocialEngine config (plugins and themes) between environments using CLI?

Ideally we'd like to migrate our config from dev/UAT environments to production using CI, but based on the official docs it seems that managing plugins and themes can be only done via the admin panel.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a **book**, **tool**, **software library**, **tutorial** or other **off-site resource** are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: > Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial

Uhm, where did you find any indication of that in my question? Added "How to..." to the beginning of the description, to make it more explicit, but I'm afraid I can't make it more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

To enable/disable any module, please check engine4_core_modules table and for production/development, please check the file application->settings->general.php